# Implementing Oauth2 with login credentials from native login page

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Oauth2 based web service. I have clientID, clientSecret, Authorization endpoint, Token endpoint and callback Url(custom schema points to an android native page). When I checked other Oauth2 based APIs, it has login Url and it will be redirected to a login web page. But in my case there is not Login URL, but it should be redirected to a native login page and on success response it should be redirected to logged in native page. How to get the access token using Oauth2?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I correctly understand your question and if your server app is Asp.Net WebAPI, then your clients (android, web browsers) can normally access /token (for example http://192.1.1.1:12345/token) to get the access token. The token then will be stored in your client apps for other requests that need authorization.

Comment: Yes, get token using Oauth2 and use it with subsequent webservice calls.

Comment: So, what is your problem here?

Comment: How to get the access token using Oauth2?

Comment: In your android app, use HttpUrlConnection or other libraries such as Volley, Retrofit, OkHttp to request the above /token I mentioned, of course you will have to provide grant_type, username and password

Comment: I tried it and working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments above, let's assume you have already had ASP.NET WebAPI as server-side app, and if your Android client app uses `HttpUrlConnection`, you can refer to the following sample code (of course, you will need to modify more to make it works as your requirement):

```
            String address = "http://<IP>:<PORT>/token";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            String requestBody;
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
            stringMap.put("grant_type", "password");
            stringMap.put("username", "bnk");
            stringMap.put("password", "bnk");

            Iterator entries = stringMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
                builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
                entries.remove();
            }
            requestBody = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            try {
                URL url = new URL(address);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
                writer.write(requestBody);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();
                urlConnection.connect();
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    // do something...
                } else {
                    // do something...
                }
                // do something...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**UPDATE:**

If you prefer [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), please refer to the following working code:

```
    private class AccessTokenRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String accessToken = null;
            OkHttpJsonRequest jsonRequest = new OkHttpJsonRequest();
            RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                    .add("grant_type", "password")
                    .add("username", "bnk")
                    .add("password", "bnk123")
                    .build();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRequest.post("http://192.168.1.100:24780/token", requestBody);
                if (!jsonObject.isNull("access_token")) {
                    accessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");                        
                }
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return accessToken;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);
            // do something such as storing the token for furture requests
        }
    }

    public class OkHttpJsonRequest {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        JSONObject post(String url, RequestBody body) throws IOException, JSONException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return new JSONObject(response.body().string());
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this library from GitHub](https://github.com/AliAbozaid/OAuth2Library).