# Verifying user credentials with REST API?

Tags: android, api, rest, android-intent, android-activity

I've set up a REST API on my site in order to return information from my database.

I'm implementing login and registration on my app right now. However, I'm not sure how to handle verifying user credentials (checking if an email is already registered, if a password meets its requirements, etc).

Since my REST API is not open to the public, would it be safe to pass the data like this:

```
/users/verify/email/{email_address}
/users/verify/password/{password}
```

Or is there a better (safer) way to do this? In other words, how can I authenticate and validate users when the login/register?

Comment: please, never send sensitive data in a url or a get Web Service, use POST to send data to your Backend in the body request.

Answer (score 3):

In REST you're talking about resources.  A resource will have some state expressed through their properties.

With your example I would ask myself: "why verify an email", "why verify a password".  Because you want to verify if a user can be registered.
So your resource will not be an email or a password but a user.

Verification is an action.  Something which does not go well with a [REST architecture](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

What do you want to verify? You want to register a new user but also verify if he's allowed to register.  So you'll try with some conditions to add a user to your collection of users.  In REST with HTTP this can be done with a POST which acts like an add(User).  The logic behind the request can then implement the verification rules on the user.

To post data just use the content body and use the headers for additional info. So I'd change my API to:

```
HTTP method: POST
Path: /users
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{"email_address":"qsdfg@sdfgh.com", "password":"qlmkdjfmqlsk"}
```

Which simplifies your API to a single entrypoint for adding a user.  Allowing or refusing to register the user can be communicated through the use of HTTP status codes and messages.

Of course sending passwords in plaintext is not a good practice but you can setup a secure connection with SSL or TLS to communicate.

Sending sensitive data in a URL is not a good practice btw.  Servers can log the url which will show everyone with access to the log the password of the user.

The login is a bit different but not that much.

You'd need a resource which uniquely links a user to his conversation with your system.

```
HTTP method: POST
Path: /authentication
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{"email_address":"qsdfg@sdfgh.com", "password":"qlmkdjfmqlsk"}
```

Response

```
Status-Code: 200
Content: 
unique-id-to-my-user
```

The authentication could call your user api to enforce the rules and then generate the id.

You could use an OAuth2 implementation to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *POST* method.

> /register with name, email, password  for User registration
>   /login with email, password for User login.

Just make sure that you do not pass the password in clear. Perform some kind of encryption on it.

Comment: And ship the client with a static preconfigured cryptographic key? It could be extracted from the client. You can send the password in the clear, but make the communication channel is secure. Use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is Asp.Net WebAPI which will return an access token for the valid user, you can use Http POST request with username and password as body content.

For sample code, please take a look at my answer in the following question

[Implementing Oauth2 with login credentials from native login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696960/implementing-oauth2-with-login-credentials-from-native-login-page)

For better security, use Https instead of Http.

Hope this helps!