# How to make a client which authenticates against ASP.NET WebAPI?

Tags: android, android-studio, asp.net-web-api, http-post, restful-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd218.jpg)I have created REST API in ASP.NET with `http://server/token` as URL.

The header having

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencode
```

The body have `grant_type` as password, username and password will get json data with token.

For further data access token can be used above method works with postman

I need to implement a client in Android Studio or Xamarin.

as urls in postman is "example.com/token"; , then in Header Key value pais for content type as ("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and in body key value pair as (grant_type:password, username:email,password:pass) and after send the response is in json format as follows { "access_token": "token", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in": 1209599, "userName": "mail@gmail.com", ".issued": "Fri, 09 Dec 2016 19:19:18 GMT", ".expires": "Fri, 23 Dec 2016 19:19:18 GMT" }
this same needed to be done in android

Comment: Can you explain more clearly how your requests are made? Is the token set with a header or parameter or maybe the body of the request? An example from postman would help a lot understanding your question.

Comment: as urls in postman is "http://example.com/token" , then in Header Key value pais for content type as ("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and in body key value pair as (grant_type:password, username:email,password:pass) and after send the response is in json format as follows  {
  "access_token": "token",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1209599,
  "userName": "mail@gmail.com",
  ".issued": "Fri, 09 Dec 2016 19:19:18 GMT",
  ".expires": "Fri, 23 Dec 2016 19:19:18 GMT"
}

Comment: i need to do the same thing in android

Comment: update the question body with what you wrote in the comments please, it'll make it easier for others to read

Comment: I think you can try my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696960/implementing-oauth2-with-login-credentials-from-native-login-page

Answer (score 1):

Include in your dependencies System.Net.Http (requires Xamarin profile 111) and then you can use that to create a HttpClient and request the token via HTTP POST (akin to what you were doing in Postman) like this..

```
_client = new HttpClient();

var uri = new Uri("http://server/token");
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
        new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", _username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", _password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
        });
HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, content);
```

Where _username and _password are strings.

Then read the response out by converting it into a Dictionary or any other reasonable alternative approach to parsing the JSON response.

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        var jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonContent);
        if (responseDict.ContainsKey("access_token"))
            _token = responseDict["access_token"];
}
```

Then once you have the token, you can include it as a default authorization value for all headers from that HttpClient instance!

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
```

Where _token is the token as it's encoded string, e.g. "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC..."

Just implemented this and to verify it's correctness - I ran it against a production environment I have set up to verify using JWTs and it worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

this works, it looks ugly but you can change it

```
    var authCredentials = "grant_type=password&username=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(LoginBindingModel.Email) + "&password=" + LoginBindingModel.Password;
    string response = await Client.MakePostFormRequest("token", authCredentials);


public static async Task<string> MakePostFormRequest(string url, string data)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl + "token");
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Accept = "*/*";
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            //request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.
            Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Dispose();
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            // Display the status.
            //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.

            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            // Clean up the streams.
            TokenViewModel TokenViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenViewModel >(responseFromServer);
            VariablesGlobales.Token = TokenViewModel.access_token;
            VariablesGlobales.LoginStamp = TokenViewModel.LoginStamp;
            reader.Dispose();
            dataStream.Dispose();
            response.Dispose();

            return responseFromServer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

And when you want to authenticate your request

```
public static async Task<string> MakePostRequest(string url, string data)
    {
        var result = "";
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BaseUrl + url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            if (VariablesGlobales.Token != "")
            {
                httpWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + VariablesGlobales.Token;
            }

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await httpWebRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));

            if (httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                result = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                result = "";
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = "";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: in android studio m working cant resolve symbol for HttpWebRequest, and where i need to put these method as its giving error lots, if you dont mind helping a bit more

Comment: oh sorry this is for Xamarin.Android in c# i suggest you to remove that tag